# Azure Application Gateway, how to link to SSL Cert on a different Azure Subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application Gateway in subscription A and a wildcard ssl cert in a Keyvault in subscription B, both under the same tenant. Is it possible to link this certificate to this application gateway?

Answer (score 6):

Continuing on from @andriy-bilous, creating a Managed Identity for an Azure Application Gateway so you can draw down certificates from your Azure Key Vault is pretty simple.

Create the Managed Identity:

1. Go to *Azure Portal*.
2. Select the search bar at the top, then search for and select "Managed Identities".
3. Select **Create**.
4. Enter your new managed identity the relivant *Resource Group* and *Region*, and a unique *Name*.
5. Now, **Review + create**, then **Create**.

Assign the rights to the Managed Identity in your Key Vault:

1. Go to your *Key Vault*.
2. Under **Settings**, select **Access policies**.
3. Select **+ Add Access Policy**.
4. Under the **Secret permissions** dropdown, select **Get**.
5. Next to *Select principal*, select **None selected**.
6. Search for the Managed Indentity you just created, and **Select**.
7. Finally, click **Add** and you're done.

Head on over to your Application Gateway, and there will be a Managed Idenity for the Key Vault and setup your HTTPS certificates.

Also, as you've aleady got a VNET setup, adding your Key Vault to the VNET via a Private Endpoint is a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Application Gateway integration with Key Vault requires a three-step configuration process:

- Create a user-assigned managed identity
- Configure your key vault
- Configure the application gateway

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs#how-integration-works

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The Gateway has a managed ID assigned to it and the managed ID has been granted get cert and get secret (I don't think the secret permission is necessary, but it has it nonetheless) on the keyvault. However, in the UI when I attempt to associate the cert with the gateway, no key vaults are listed. I haven't attempted to use the cli yet, that might be my next step, but I expect that if I can't see it in the UI I'll get an error via the CLI.

Comment: @RaymondGrumney did you try integrate Application Gateway integration with Key Vault  using CLI?

Comment: I did. az cli, my usual management tool, just errors out for me. `--key-vault-secret-id` seems to be in preview, or I've mangled the id (though I tried many variables). I see there might be a way to do it in Powershell, but PS is greek to me.

Comment: You could try to use these commands in PS:
Connect-AzAccount
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription yoursubscription

$certificate = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName MYKEYVAULT -Name "cert1"
$secretId = $certificate.SecretId.Replace($certificate.Version, "")
New-AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate -Name "SSLCert1" -KeyVaultSecretId $secretId


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-keyvault-ps

Comment: This created an SSL certificate that isn't associated with a GW. I tried variants of AzApplicationGatewaySslCertificate (Set-, Add-), and haven't been able to assign any cert in this manner to a GW even on the same Subscription.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?
Please run Powershell script with Debug option

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue. As of Nov 2021, based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/key-vault-certs), the Key Vault instance must be in the same subscription as Application Gateway.

> Azure Application Gateway currently supports only Key Vault accounts in the same subscription as the Application Gateway resource. Choosing a key vault under a different subscription than your Application Gateway will result in a failure.

Comment: Checked linked documentation today and it is now supported, but only via automation tools (ARM / Bicep etc) rather than through the portal.